# USB hub raspberryPi

Tags: usb-hub

I've been searching for a host-powered USB hubs with Raspberry Pi and discovered that most of the hubs are sort of built for the raspberry Pi device.

I intend on using the USb port for serial communicaton between multiple arduino development boards

Can i buy any USB 2.0 hub for my raspberry-pi model or I need a hub specifically built for it?

Answer (score 2):

Don't know what you mean when you say that "most of the [host-powered] hubs are built for the Raspberry Pi". But let us be clear: A [host-powered USB hub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hub#Power) is NOT generally what you want to use with a Raspberry Pi.

Why? Because, as [this article points out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hub#Power), the Raspberry Pi will then have to supply the power for all the USB devices that are plugged into the hub. And since the RPi is unable to provide much power beyond what it needs for its own use, this is usually a bad idea.

Instead, for your RPi to which you connect Arduino boards, you should buy a a self-powered hub.

Comment: Thanks i meant my search was related to the raspberryPi so most of the results were hubs buit for the raspberry pi Which hub would you recommend for a raspberrypi so i know i am safe??(no backfeeds)

Comment: @DesHam: My recommendation was in the last sentence. I've edited it slightly to make it clear. Buy a `self-powered hub` for your RPi if you are going to connect several Arduinos to it.

Answer (score 1):

USB is simply a standard.

You could use a normal hub, if that does not draw too much power. See a list [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/faqs/). Basically do not draw more than 500 mA on any board and you are safe.

If you need more than that, get a USB hub that supplies power to the USB devices.